# Read file from remote machine

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have website hosted in iis7.5.

My requirement is, develop the c# code to read a file from the other machine.

Is it possible to read a file from remote machine?

Comment: Is the remote machine under the same network as of website hosted machine?

Answer (score 1):

Use [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) to read file.

**The important issues** ; The file must be opened and accessible in order for you to be able to read a file on remote

**In my opinion**

The files should be kept and share on the server where IIS is published.

> **Please check this list**
>
> - **try to ping through command prompt** -- ping RemoteIp
> - **try opened file from Folder Address path** -- //RemoteIpOrMachineName/ShareFolder/FileName.txt

if there is not problem access to file try this code

```
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"\\IPAddress or remote machine Name\ShareFolder\FileName.txt");
```

Answer (score -1):

what i would suggest is to map a driver from remote folder and read them a local file files. plaase see the link below.

https://www.serverintellect.com/support/techfaq/drive-rdp/